# VSCode cannot input data

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm a noob in C++ and I have VSCode running in Windows11 , with the typical extensions for C++ and MinGW. I am running a little code in this IDE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
 int num;
 cout << "Number: " ;
 cin >> num;
 return 0;
 }
```

It is something basic for this test, but when I run it in the output option I cannot enter anything, neither letters nor numbers. Nothing comes up in the terminal option either. The code executes without errors and VSCODE does not give any information.
Instead, if I run the .exe file from outside the editor it works perfectly.
I don't know if it's my editor configuration error or some other problem, in Ubuntu or MacOS this has never happened to me.

I appreciate the help in advance.
All the best.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not an IDE, it's a text editor.
How do you execute your program?

Comment: Oh, I thinks it’s and IDE, thanks for the correction. The code runs with MinGW I think

Comment: You should be able to enter the number in the terminal tab. Or at least that's what my VSCode is doing.

Comment: Yeah, VSCODE do that in a Ubuntu VM that I have, but not in my Windows. I don’t know if it’s a  error in my configuration of the text editor